# persistent listview in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, markup, persistent, jquery-mobile-listview

In jquery mobile you can have a navbar which has a class of persistent which makes the nav button which is chosen to highlight in a different colour. this indicates to the user where he/she is located within the menu. Is it possible to have that same effect on a listview? What I am trying to do is when a user selects an anchor within the list it stays highlighted. So if the user goes back to the same list the user can see which option in the list was previously selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WA7qZ/

I think this is what you want. Unfortunately there isn't any jQuery Mobile built in functionality for this so it has to be done manually.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>`enter code here`
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="profile">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <h3>Example</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-theme='a'><a id='a1' href='#' rel='external'>TEST 1</a></li>
                <li data-theme='a'><a id='a2' href='#' rel='external'>TEST 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='divtest'>

        </div>
        <!--/content-->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        </div>
        <!--/footer-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a href="#profile" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).live('pagebeforeshow','#profile', function(e,data){
    $(document).off('click', '#mylist li').on('click', '#mylist li',function(e) {
        setNewTheme('a', '#mylist li');
        setNewTheme('b', $(this));
        $.mobile.changePage("#second", {
            reloadPage: false,
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: false
        });        
    });      
});

function setNewTheme(newTheme, object) {
    $.mobile.activePage.find(object).removeClass('ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-up-d ui-btn-up-e ui-btn-hover-a ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-hover-d ui-btn-hover-e').addClass('ui-btn-up-' + newTheme ).attr('data-theme', newTheme );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programatically. Meaning at this time in my webapp with the listview I can select an href but when it moves into the next page I have a button there that can continue going tru the previous list without going back to the page. So lets say I click on the first value within the list and when it carries me to the page I click to move to another href within the list can I update the active list member also?